# Was macht der Tabak im "Anno Tobak"?

Tags: etymology, proverb

Selten hört man den Ausdruck „Anno Tobak“, der wie „Anno dazumal“ scherzhaft auf eine unbestimmte, lange, meist zurückliegende Zeit hinweisen soll.

Manchmal wird „Anno Tobak“ auch für eine unbestimmt lange Zeit in der Zukunft eingesetzt:

> Und bei der Union darf man wohl noch bis **anno Tobak** warten, bis sie überhaupt mal ein Programm vorlegt. <sup>[Hamburger Abendblatt, 2009](http://www.abendblatt.de/politik/deutschland/article108511831/Wir-duerfen-nicht-nur-auf-die-Wirtschaftskrise-schauen.html)</sup>

Ein frühes Beispiel habe ich bei Hoffmann von Fallersleben „Das Parlament zu Schnappel“ (1830) gefunden:

> *Krebs:* Das errinnert mich an eine Geschichte von **Anno Tobak**. In einer Gesellschaft wurde behauptet, französische Verse ließen sich nicht gut verdeutschen.

Allerdings ist mir völlig unklar, wie lange es den Ausdruck gibt, und wer ihn in welcher Bedeutung geprägt haben könnte. Offenbar muss er aus einer Zeit stammen, in der Tabakkonsum schon gebräuchlich war, aber als man zu Tabak noch *Tobak* sagte, also vermutlich irgendwann ab dem 16. Jahrhundert und [noch vor 1850](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Tabak%2C%20Tobak&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTabak%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CTobak%3B%2Cc0).

Gibt es irgendwo eine nähere zeitliche Eingrenzung und konkretere Hinweise zur Etymologie?

Comment: Nach Ngram, erst seit 1900 in Büchern zu finden. Also nach 1850.

Comment: Redensarten-Index: "Die lang gestreckte Antilleninsel Tobago gab den Rauchrohren der Indianer den Namen. Als Tobaco und später Tabaco gelangt das Wort 1579 nach Deutschland. Anno Tobak ist scherzhaft Anno Domini (im Jahre des Herrn) nachgebildet und meint eigentlich: in jenen alten Zeiten, als man statt Tabak noch Tobak sagte "

Comment: @Em1: das Zitat oben ist von **1830** und damals sagte man gerade noch "Tobak" wenn man dem Google-ngram Glauben schenken kann (und Wilhelm Busch Max & Moritz (1856): *Nun war dieser brave Lehrer / Von dem Tobak ein Verehrer,*)

Comment: @Em1 Ich würde eher sagen, dass damit die Zeit gemeint ist, als bei uns das Tabakrauchen *aufkam*, also ein paar hundert Jahre früher, so ca. nach dem 30-jährigen Krieg, der mit den Soldaten anscheinend das Rauchen nach Deutschland gebracht hat.

Comment: Es gibt auch noch "Anno dunnemals", offensichtlich eine Verballhornung von "Anno dazumal". Das wäre auch meine Interpretation von "Anno Tobak".

Comment: @tofro Nur zur Erinnerung: Tabak wurde nicht nur geraucht, sondern auch gekaut und geschnupft.

Comment: @Takkat Ich hätte expliziter sein sollen. "Anno Tobak" als Phrase ist seit 1900 attestiert. Das Wort an sich ist natürlich schon älter.

Comment: Ich möchte an dieser Stelle anmerken, dass mir der Ausdruck völlig unbekannt ist (und ich ihn auch nicht sofort erschließen konnte). Regionalismus?

Comment: @Marzipanherz: soweit ich weiß immer noch (geschnupft oder gekaut), nur nicht mehr so häufig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laut GFDS, die sich auf Lutz Röhrich beziehen, bezieht sich das auf den Zeitpunkt, zu dem das Tabakrauchen aufkam. Hier zu finden:

> Neben der Redewendung anno dazumal oder anno dunnemals kann wohl auch anno Tobak zu den wenigen allgemein bekannten gezählt werden. Sie bezieht sich auf den Zeitpunkt, als das Tabakrauchen aufkam, also auf einen Zeitpunkt, der sehr lange zurückliegt (Lutz Röhrich, Das große Lexikon der sprichwörtlichen Redensarten, Freiburg 1991, Bd. 1, S. 87–88). <sup>[GFDS](http://gfds.de/anno/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Nein, außer der Information "um 1900" und der selbst gelieferten Bedeutungserklärung lässt sich nichts mehr genaueres mit den herkömmlichen Mitteln herausfinden.